# No working in the animation was running xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uinavigationcontroller, ios5

I'm in the coding Objective-C of xcode4.2.

But stopped working on an animated navigation iOS xcode4.2.
The project was reconfigured in xcode4.2 xcode3.x was originally developed.

In the time of reconstruction NewProject "Mastar-Detail Application" is selected.

Basically, the transition of navigation

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

are using.

What was working in a way that slides horizontally in xcode3.x,
Once you build xcode4.2, eliminating the slide animation
The sister looks like a page changes instantaneously.

Please tell me how to move an animated slide xcode4.2.

Thank you.

Comment: The code appears correct. Presuming that "view" is an instance of UIViewController and not UIView.

Comment: Hi, drekka.Fix UIViewController to view. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear about the problems your described at beginning. :(
But on this question: **how to move an animated slide xcode4.2.**
Well, `NavigationController`'s `pushViewController:animated:` method has its slide animation if you set the `animated` to `YES`. Like the code snippet below:

```
UIViewController * yourNewViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[yourNewViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[yourNewViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourNewViewController animated:YES];
[yourNewViewController release];
```

Note: You must push the `ViewController` not the `View` to it.

---

If you want to **imitate** this slide animation for other views without `Navigation Controller`, you can do like this:

```
UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-320.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Note: In this way, the navigationBar's titleView will not change, you need to change it by yourself if you want.

Comment: Hi, Kjuly.Thank you for your answer.
It is necessary to devise a title of my question. I get back home and immediately try. very very Thank you!

Comment: @Kijuly, In addition, the ViewController I pass the following properties.

Comment: @Kijuly, I tried the first answer. But did not change behavior.
I am using this code.
`nextViewController *= [[nextViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"nextViewNib" bundle: nil];
[nextViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
nextViewController.somePropaty = self.somePropaty;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];` help me.

Comment: @IoOhta, check whether your `self.navigationController` is `nil` or not.

Comment: @Kijuly I was confirmed. The following code fragment. `NSLog ("@ navicon = %@")`
The results were as follows."navicon =  <UINavigationController: 0x375f30>"

Comment: @IoOhta It's weird. :? What your class inherit from?

Comment: @Kijuly I'm sorry I'm late. I have a class that is inherited `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hi @IoOhta, you can have a look at the demo in [GITHUB](https://github.com/Kjuly/ios-demo/tree/master/TestForDelegate/TestForDelegate), and figured it out how it works. :)

Comment: @Kijuly Thanks! I can try it!! Thank you!

Comment: @IoOhta u'r welcome. U can just download it and use it. That's a complete project. :)

Comment: @Kijuly Long time no see. It's problem is fix!!! I referred to your project of GITHUB. I've tried is the following. (1) Removed the window from the main xib. (2) AppDelegate added the following code to reference the GITHUB. `self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
nextViewController *next_view = [[nextViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:next_view];
    [next_view release];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];`

Comment: @Kijuly Really appreciate it can be resolved. Thank you so much!!